# Add api_key on every request with Rack middleware

Tags: ruby, devise, rack, middleware, activeresource

I work with Devise token_authentication service and ActiveResource client. I wish set automatically :auth_token params in every requests !

I tried this, but this doesn't work...

```
class AuthApp

    def initialize(app)
        @app = app
    end

    def call(env)
        status, headers, response = @app.call(env)

        request = Rack::Request.new(env)
        request.params[:auth_token] = 'jCxKPj8wJJdOnQJB8ERy'

        [status, headers, response]
    end

end
```

Any idea ?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. In fact, I had it working in Rails 3.0.7 and an older version of Rack. Now, broken. I can see in the Rack app that the newly merged params are there, but they're not hanging out for the ride into Rails.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a recent copy of rack that includes [this pull request](https://github.com/rack/rack/pull/381), you can use `Rack::Request#update_param`:

```
request = Rack::Request.new(env)
request.update_param :auth_token, 'jCxKPj8wJJdOnQJB8ERy'
```

That will persist in the `env` that is passed among middlewares (and to Rails).

Comment: This doesn't seem to be in the gem released version, both master and the gem released are at 1.4.1 and only master has this?  Am I missing something?

Comment: You're correct - this feature is not in 1.4.1. Hopefully they release 1.5 soon... it's been a **long** time.

Comment: Thanks for the quick heads up.. that said your code and the reference still helped me get my answer, so thanks.